# Android ListView custom adapter basics: getView() position always 0

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

GetView position is always 0.  Following the basic concepts shown at http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview, my code is as follows:

```
public void DisplayUserList()
{   // Get data list from SQL Database
    UserList = mySQLiteHelper.getUserList(ACTIVE);

    // Get ListView
    user_listview_control = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.user_listview);

    // Get Adapter
    userAdapter = new UserAdapter();

    // Bind it all together
    user_listview_control.setAdapter(userAdapter);

}   // end DisplayUserList()

// User List Base Adapter
public class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return UserList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Structures.user_struct getItem(int arg0){
        return UserList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0){return arg0;}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2){
        if (arg1 == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Settings.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            try {
                arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlist_item, arg2, false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                String errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
            }
        }

        TextView username = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView firstname = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.userfirstname);
        TextView lastname = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.userlastname);
        TextView lastlogin = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.userlastlogin);

        UserData = UserList.get(position);   //(always zero)

        username.setText(user.username);
        firstname.setText(user.user_firstname);
        lastname.setText(user.user_lastname);

        if (user.user_lastlogin_date.length() == 0) {
            lastlogin.setText("--");
        } else {
            lastlogin.setText(user.user_lastlogin_date);
        }

        // OnClickListener for this row.
        arg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "User Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Integer position = (Integer) view.getTag();
            }
        });

        return arg1;
    }
}   // end UserAdapter()
```

The sqlite data table has three items that are returned in the UserList defined as:

```
public List<Structures.user_struct> UserList;
```

When user_listview_control.setAdapter is called, getCount() is called (returning value of 3) repeatedly just before getView() is called.  In getView(), the position is always 0.  The resulting ListView display is one line only with the first item of the database. [note: if I force position = 1 or 2, code returns the next User in that list].  I don't see where I am off.  Could it be the xml layout constraining the display?   When I run the above referenced sample code it does work as a simple xml layout.  So???

Comment: Post your layout file `userlist_item.xml`

Comment: Can you post mySQLiteHelper.getUserList(ACTIVE); method?

Comment: Can you post your "user_listview" xml?

Answer (score 0):

GetUserList:

```
public List<Structures.user_struct> getUserList(int isActive) {
    // Get List of Users in database
    //  Filter isActive 0 = Not, 1 = Is, 2 = ALL
    //  NOte: Is userList database does not exist, create it.

    Structures.user_struct UserData = new Structures.user_struct();
    List<Structures.user_struct> UserList = new     ArrayList<Structures.user_struct>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String strSQL = "select * from " + Structures.USER_TABLE_NAME ;
    if (isActive < 2){      // filter is or is not active Only
        strSQL += " where " + Structures.USER_COL_IS_ACTIVE + "=" + isActive;
    }

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strSQL, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

        UserData.user_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_ID));
        UserData.user_is_active = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_IS_ACTIVE));
        UserData.username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_USERNAME));
        UserData.user_password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_PASSWORD));
        UserData.user_firstname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_FIRSTNAME));
        UserData.user_lastname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_LASTNAME));
        UserData.user_date_created = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_DATECREATED));
        UserData.user_date_updated = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_DATEUPDATED));
        UserData.user_lastlogin_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Structures.USER_COL_DATELASTLOGIN));

        // Copy UserData to ArrayList of structures
        UserList.add(UserData);

        cursor.moveToNext();

        UserData = new Structures.user_struct();
    }

    return UserList;
}   // end getUserList()
```

UserData

```
 // User Data Structure
 public static class user_struct {
    public int user_id;
    public int user_is_active;      // 0=not, 1=is
    public String username;
    public String user_password;
    public String user_firstname;
    public String user_lastname;
    public int user_permission_level_id;
    public String user_date_created;
    public String user_date_updated;
    public String user_lastlogin_date;
}   // end user_structure()
```

userlist_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/user_list_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/User_List"
        android:text="username"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/userfirstname"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/user_list_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/User_List"
        android:text="first name"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/userlastname"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/user_list_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/User_List"
        android:text="last name"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/userlastlogin"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/user_list_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/User_List"
        android:text="last login"/>

</LinearLayout>
```